# Spring 3.1: DataSource not autowired to @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.1.0M2 and trying to move my configs to java beans. But I encounter following error:

> 2011-09-14 18:43:42.301:WARN:/:unavailable org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class ru.mystamps.web.config.DbConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ru.mystamps.web.config.DbConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null

Mapping from `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            ru.mystamps.web.config.MvcConfig,
            ru.mystamps.web.config.DbConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

`DbConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/datasource.xml")
public class DbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter =
            new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(dialectClassName);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        final Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", formatSql);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.charset", "UTF-8");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager =
            new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

`spring/datasource.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/database.properties" />

    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="test">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql" />
        </jdbc:embedded-database>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

I expect that bean `dataSource` will be created after importing `datasource.xml` but I always got this error.

TIA

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with profiles? Have you tried to run it without them?

Comment: @axtavt when I removed profiles and leave only `dataSource` with `jdbc:embedded-database` I've got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found cause of error, it occurs only when I manually define `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`:

```
   @Bean
   public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
           // enable injection of EntityManager to beans with @PersistenceContext annotation
           return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
   }
```

I'm sorry because I didn't post full code in the question (because I supposed that this bean does not matter). When I removed this definition, everything works as expected. Also I found that in my case this bean have been already registered:

> Note: A default PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the
>   "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags.
>   Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you intend
>   to specify a custom PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition.

(quote comment from [`org.springframework.orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0e5614289064a47a99758a95c8d9baa464ed9b56/org.springframework.orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L152))