# How to set some Hibernate properties in Spring JPA Web Application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I am trying to get rid of the typical `persistence.xml` file in Spring JPA web application. So far, I have managed to inject the `EntityManager` successfully with the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource( this.restDataSource() );
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan( new String[ ] { "com.jverstry" } );
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("MyMy");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(){
         {
            // JPA properties ...
         }
        };

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );

        return factoryBean;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource(){

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );

        return transactionManager;

    }

}
```

I have managed to move the properties of my persistence.xml for the datasource:

```
<properties>
    ... 
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
</properties>
```

but how to I set the two remaining hibernate properties above? Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416024/spring-3-1-datasource-not-autowired-to-configuration-class

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring provides a way to configure these options in provider-independent way using `AbstractJpaVendorAdapter` (`setDatabase()` and `setGenerateDdl()`, though `setGenerateDdl()` doesn't take DDL mode).

Alternatively, you can pass arbitrary properties to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` using `setJpaProperties()` (or `setJpaPropertyMap()`):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);
```

Comment: How to do the same in application context xml file?

Answer (score 6):

This is the old question but might help someone who is using XML for configuration.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test-jpa"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProxy"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="10"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.