# Is it possible to set hibernate.show_sql for Query programmatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use Hibernate with Spring and initialize it with `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean with `hibernate.show_sql=false` in JpaProperties of it. So, I disabled SQL output of Hibernate, but I want to print SQL only for some Query, that I want to debug.

Is it possible to set hibernate.show_sql for Query programmatically, to don't print all SQL queries at runtime, but print them only for some Query?

And no, it's not a duplicate. Because, everything, that explained in suggested answer is already done in my app. I need to enable SQL logging not for all Queries in my app, but only for one Query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set some Hibernate properties in Spring JPA Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237003/how-to-set-some-hibernate-properties-in-spring-jpa-web-application)

Comment: Nope, it's already done in my app. I need to enable SQL logging not for all Queries in my app, but only for one Query.

Comment: The only idea like enable logging and filter all except one query... kind of:)